# How to solve the problem of debugging with in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

Hello i have a problem of debugging in VS with iis that is :

[image]

so what i should do always is :

[image]

and here there is the pool of application in IIS :

[image]

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Exactly what steps are you doing to get the error?

Answer (score 2):

Two options

1. In Visual Studio attach a debug built project via `Debug` -> `Attach To Process` and filter/select `w3wp.exe`. If you have multiple sites/services running its best to put different sites/services on different app pools. That way you can identify which one to attach to. Below my service I attach to is on App Pool 8.

[image]

2. `F5` debug the site/service. You may need to change some web.config values like such as `allowunlisted` if dealing with restful web services. Also setting the `debug` in compilation is helpful `<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true"/>` as an example.

Comment: didn't find w3wp.exe in the list when i did debug - attach to process

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as Administrator and select `Show all processes from all users`.

Comment: where i found all users ?

Comment: Its a checkbox under the process list.

Comment: when i click attach i have an attach security waring

Comment: One needs to run Visual Studio in Admin mode.

Comment: I did it and i have this attach security waring